# Strange Item on DHCP Client Table

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ip, dhcp

I was recently having internet connection issues and looked on my router's DHCP Client Table. An item that stuck out was the name of my neighbor's WiFi Network. The table listed "Neighbor's WiFi Network Name" and next to it as Interface Type: LAN. As I'm aware DHCP distributes dynamic IP Addresses, meaning I am giving my neighbor an IP address? I then clicked "Delete" next to the network on the table. Two days later, after the LAN item is deleted, I see a new item, prefixed with my neighbor's name, but with the interface type: "Wireless" Is something nefarious going on here, or am I being paranoid? My router is the Linksys E2500.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your security keys and\or level of security, sounds like they are extending your wifi to their network. Which you would need your security detail to to.

Page 8 in the manual. use WPA2
http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/MAN_E2500_3425-01547E_E-Router_EN.pdf

Comment: Ok, I have changed the password to a new WPA2 password (was WPA2/Mixed before). I never gave anyone the password, would it be possible within reason for them to be cracking it somehow? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Always potentially the case. You could lock down your network to MAC addresses if you wanted to head down that path. Once you make the change report back if the device re-attaches after some time, might give some clue if they had to spend some time to get back on it.

Comment: Alright, I've added a Wireless MAC filter and will report back if the show up on the DHCP list again. Thanks Again!